# Timing violations in interfacing Flash with MSP430 using SPI interface

Tags: spi

I was going through a schematic where MSP430 is interfaced with SPI flash, w25q128fv[image: SPI timing specifications of Flash and Microcontroller are given in the following image]

During Data transfer between Microcontroller and Flash:
Flash timing specification states that its Data in hold time as 3ns(Minimum) , and microcontroller output data hold time is -8ns(minimum) , which means master changes its state before 8ns before the clock change. Whether this is hold time violation?

During Data transfer between Flash and Microcontroller:
Flash timing specifications states that its data out valid time is maximum 7ns , but the data in set up time of microcontroller is minimum 25 ns. Whether this condition is set up time violation?
In both above conditions whether faithful data transfer would take place between microcontroller and flash. If it’s a violation whether it can be taken care in Firmware coding?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is believe these are the times one needs to concern them selves with as the speed of the [SPI bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) increases. If you do not operate the SPI bus at its upper limit, you shouldn't have to worry about these times.

A labeled timing diagram for each part would help.

But, guessing, the Data In Hold Time is likely the minimum amount of time necessary for the MOSI data to be stable for the flash to latch it.The SIMO (aka MOSI) Output Data Hold Time is likely (as you stated) the point where master changes the data relative to the next master clock change.  The point here may be that if the  master clock period is less than 8ns + 3ns = 11ns, it may not be long enough for the slave to latch the data dependably.  That is to say, the master may change the data too fast for the slave.

Going on, the slave's Clock Low To Output Valid time is maximum 7ns.  And the master's SOMI (aka MISO) Input Data Setup Time is minimum 25ns.  This may be a bit tricky.  It could be that the master is ready to latch in the data 25ns after the master has change the clock output.  Or it could be that we need to wait 25ns after we are assured the slave's data output is correct.  In which case we need to wait 7ns + 25ns = 32ns before we are assured we can successfully latch in the MISO data.

Using just these constraints, as there might be others which need to be considered, we have a maximum SPI bus clock of about 15MHz.  Unless you need to transfer large amounts of data, this speed appears higher than most designers would use.